# Cannot convert value of type 'NSAttributedString.Key' to expected dictionary key type 'String' error(swift4.2)

Tags: ios, swift4.2, nsattributedstringkey

Error in below two lines of code while upgrading from swift 3 to swift 4.2

```
let lineattribute : [String: Any] = [
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor(hexString: "#0f88b7ff")!,
    NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName : NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue
]

let attributeString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "View travelling details", attributes: lineattribute)
```

[image: error]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In **Swift 4.2** you have to use `NSAttributedString.Key` instead of `String`

```
let lineattribute : [NSAttributedString.Key : Any] = [
    .foregroundColor : UIColor(hexString: "#0f88b7ff"),
    .underlineStyle : NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue
]

let attributeString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "View traveling details", attributes: lineattribute)
```